# caja and QT applications - how to set QT_SCALE_FACTOR

Tags: mate, qt, caja

On this system (19.04 MATE with latest NVIDIA)  QT applications play with oversized menus and window decorations. To correct I set

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

into my .bashrc and this works when I call up an application from the command line.

However when caja calls an associated QT application, this environment variable is not being set. I have tried adding it to

```
~/.config/caja/desktop-metadata
```

and to

```
/etc/environment
```

but it has no effect.

Where can I set this?

Comment: Have you looked at the QT4/5 config tools? For Qt5, install `qt5ct`; for Qt4, install `qt4-qtconfig`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes I have 5. Perhaps I should install 4 as well? I'll try that.

Comment: Are you using Nvidia graphics card and drivers? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenBoston see related post on [UM community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/workarounds-for-apps-that-dont-support-hidpi/15875?u=norbert_x).